# Replacing Google Cloud Print in Raspbian based order printer

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, google-cloud

For the past couple of years, I have been running an automated order printer for packing orders from my webshop.

Until now, I have made the webserver create a PDF of the order contents, and sent that to Google Cloud Print. My Raspbian + Thermal printer setup has listened to the printer through Google Cloud Print in Chromium and printed all orders flawlessly within a couple of seconds.

Fast forward a couple of years, Google has now closed Cloud Print and I am looking for another viable solution..

Since the webserver is already creating the PDF, my current idea is to send this file to either DropBox/Google Drive/Email/FTP or with some queueing service and make Raspian listen to changes with a regularly running python script that receive the file and print it.

However, I am a little bit concerned with the speed I can get using these methods - I am used to orders being printed within seconds from being accepted, and I would really like to achieve that again.

Any ideas on how to proceed most efficiently from here would be greatly appreciated. As would recommendations for specific libraries/repositories that I can utilize without having to do things from scratch that has probably been done thousands of times before would.

Comment: Do you already have any incoming internet-facing ports open on your raspian system (which is presumably behind a firewall/router)? Presumably your webserver is in the cloud? Can you keep an ssh connection open to your webserver ?

Comment: I could do that, but I would prefer to avoid if possible. I am rarely physically near the setup, so the more I can control from the distance and less possible culprits, the better.. I am eager to hear your suggestion though :-)

Comment: You could add a websocket to your web server; this would give you a permanent connection over which to send immediate notifications or even complete pdfs. Or you could do an ssh from the raspian to the web server and, assuming it is running Linux, use inotifywait to immediately notice new pdf files in a directory, or perhaps tail some log file to notice new pdfs, then send them back over the same ssh channel.